# Google maps in modal lat lng from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

i try 3 days to fix it but i dont know:(

i have now a google map showing in modal.
Now i want show the respose lat lng from ajax in google maps...

can somebody help me?

So I want the following:

When the submit button is clicked, data is sent to test.php(Ajax). It retrieves information from the database (Lat/Lng) and sends that response.

then the Lat/LNG from ajax must be imported into the string or something

Sorry my english is not very good.

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" id="openModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <body onload = "loadMap()">
                <div id = "Map" style = " height:345px;"></div>
            </body>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>


<script>
var load = null;

var lat = null;
var lng = null;
 $(document).ready(function ()
 {
    $('#openModal').on('click', function () 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');  
                    lat = response.lat;
                    lng = response.lng;
                    load = 'yes';
    
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    $('#myModal .modal-title').text('Oops...');
                    $('#myModal .modal-body').html('Something wrong...');                    
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
 });

</script>

      <script>
         function loadMap() {

if(load != null)
{
var myStyles =[
                {
                    featureType: "poi",
                    elementType: "labels",
                    stylers: [
                          { visibility: "off" }
                    ]
                }
            ]; 

            var mapOptions = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                mapTypeControl: false,
                navigationControl: true,
                scrollwheel: true,
                zoom:15,
                streetViewControl: false,
                styles: myStyles
            }    
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map"),mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.2731316, 6.872064),
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"),
                map: map,
            });    
}
         }
      </script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAHm61JhhV9RmLapIip0MfW7F7hUdh69os&callback=loadMap&v=weekly"
    ></script>
```

I've tried everything but it doesn't work

Comment: How is it failing? What happens?

Comment: What do you get if you write `console.log(response);` just after `success: function (response) {`?

Comment: var load is now stay null.. i want when click button load not null. but it is not working.. also the lat and lng var stay null...  why its not change the value?

Comment: @iMootje see working example in my answer

Comment: @iMootje - in addition to commenting on answers provided it is customary & polite to upvote/accept answers that resolve your problem ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So using your php json code, hosted here as an example...

https://dev.joshmoto.wtf/stackoverflow/76741713/test2.php

Which when opened outputs this json...

`{"success":true,"lat":"52.370216","lng":"4.895168"}`

A few notes:

- Why you using `<body onload = "loadMap()"><div id = "Map" style = " height:345px;"></div></body>` inside you modal html. Body tag cant be here.
- Use bootstrap 3 modal js events to load map when modal is opened.
- When I tried your code I couldn't get modal js show event to actually fire, but then I used html example for scripts etc from [Bootstrap 3 Getting Started docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started) and event starting working.

Then if I run this in a html file, see working link below...

https://dev.joshmoto.wtf/stackoverflow/76741713/

See html code below from the link above

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Google maps in modal lat lng from ajax</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h2>Modal Example</h2>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- empty map div -->
                        <div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>
        function loadMap(lat,lng) {
            let myStyles = [
                {
                    featureType: "poi",
                    elementType: "labels",
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "off" }
                    ]
                }
            ];
            let mapOptions = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                mapTypeControl: false,
                navigationControl: true,
                scrollwheel: true,
                zoom: 15,
                streetViewControl: false,
                styles: myStyles
            }
            let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
            let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png"),
                map: map,
            });
        }

        // on ready
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // when myModal show event is fired
            $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

                // get our php ajax response
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    timeout: 1000,
                    url: 'https://dev.joshmoto.wtf/stackoverflow/76741713/test2.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {

                        // load map in modal using lat long from response
                        loadMap(response.lat, response.lng);

                    }
                });

            // when myModal show event is fired
            }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

                // remove map when modal is closed
                $('#map').empty();

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Remember you need include your API key code in order the map to work on your domain like this...

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAHm61JhhV9RmLapIip0MfW7F7hUdh69os"></script>
```

But don't add `callback=loadMap`, as we are already calling `loadMap` when the modal opens via `show.bs.modal` event.

Comment: @iMootje you're very welcome! Any chance you can mark my answer as accepted please? Thanks